# Can D3 or CrossFilter be used to aggregate totals from multidimensional datasets?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

**Question:** When provided a multidimensional json structure that lacks key:values for some nodes, is it possible to reduce the structure in D3 or CrossFilter to aggregate totals accross each node that has a unique identifier?

Using plain object notation, I'm able to filter on just on subset of data: `data.map.exe.Program_Files`.  I would like to calculate and group from Class and Type located 3 nodes down from the map notation regardless of the parent node value. The Donut Chart would be used to filter on (ps1, exe, dll, etc..)

**Example Script:**
[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8RoBJL?p=preview)

**Note:** I have no control over the dataset and required to maintain the structure of the current data consumed by other D3 controls. So flattening into a new Object Array would lose binding with other controls.

Sample Subset of dataset, see data.json on plunker:

```
{   
"map": {
    "ps1": {
        "User": [],
        "Program_Files": [],
        "System_Files": [
            {       
                "class": "dir",
                "type": "ps1",
                "total": 10,
                "handled": 5,
                "nothandled": 5,
                "percentHandled": 0.0,
                "id": 1,
                "directory": "c:\\windows\\system32\\"              
            }
        ],
        "Temp": [],
        "Public": []
    },
    "dll": {
        "User": [],
        "Program_Files": [],
        "System_Files": [
            {       
                "class": "dir",
                "type": "dll",
                "total": 1000,
                "handled": 685,
                "nothandled": 315,
                "percentHandled": 0.0,
                "id": 1,
                "directory": "c:\\windows\\system32\\"              
            }
        ],
        "Temp": [],
        "Public": []
    }....
```

Comment: Is your concern about losing binding because the data structure itself will change? This will not work with Crossfilter. Once an object is added to Crossfilter, it should not change. You can use the `crossfilter.add` and `crossfilter.remove` methods to manage mutating your Crossfilter. These methods are obviously limited, but those are the sacrifices we need to make to get the level of interactivity Crossfilter can offer.

Comment: Ethan, the data structure is static, so I don't have a need to use cross filter.add/remove.  Where I'm stuck is the inability to aggregate all the total, handled, nothandled sums because I'm limited in accessing a single elements object array using plain object notation: data.map.exe.Program_Files  It would be great if I could wildcard the last 2 elements: data.map.[*].[*], else I feel this data needs to be flattened before I can truly leverage the power of D3 and CrossFilter. I could flatten on the fly into a new array object,but the I would lose binding with other d3 controls on the page.

Comment: Flatten it when you create the Crossfilter so that you can reference the current binding? After that, bindings shouldn't change the data in the cross

Comment: ... Crossfilter object anyway (SO's mobile interface for comments strikes again!)

Comment: Ethan, thanks again!  I was able to have the providing interface flatten the data structure.  Instantly, working with the data became easy to manage now. I've also incorporated your Reductio library, processing a massive dataset with phenomenal responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

After further research and guidance, the final solution was to flatten the structure into a single object array.  One can still process multi-deminsional json structures when a key:value element exists, this was not my case, so the format condition forced me to flatten the structure.